# Get filtered relationships in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Is there a way to get a core data entity and filter the relationships? For example if I have a `Parent` entity and a `Children` entity. `Children` are assigned to parents. I can get a `Parent` entity and have only the `Children` with `Blonde` hair and that are `Male`.

I know I can just get all the children then filter them after I have the object but if I change the children assigned to the parent with the filtered results, it messes up the inverse.

Comment: *"... but if I change the children assigned to the parent with the filtered results ..."* - why would you do that? - You can either filter `theParent.children`, or execute a fetch request on the Children entity with some predicate "parent = ... AND hairColor = ...". What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MartinR When I run a fetch I get all the parents with the children. However I just need the parents object with specific children. Because of this I usually run a `filterArrayWithPredicate` on the children to get the ones I need then set the `theParents.children` to the filtered results. Doing it this way breaks the inverse.

Comment: Setting `theParent.children` to the filtered results is probably a bad idea. You could use a custom method (as in the answer below), or perhaps define a "fetched property" in the Core Data model inspector. I have no practical experience with fetched properties, but according to the documentation, their advantage is that the results are cached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily filter the children or simple prepare fetch request with predicate that will perform a proper query for you.

If you want to have it 'in' your object, you can add a method in `Parent`'s category that will filter it for you, not messing the relationship:

```
- (NSSet *)childrenMaleAndBlonde {
   return [self.children filteredSetUsingPredicate:...];
}
```

When you filter that way the relationship will not be broken.

Comment: This was actually perfect. I did it a bit different by setting a property inside the model with the NSSet instead of having a method that did the filtering.